# what do the @ (at sign) means in TypeScript/Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I'm starting to work on a VueJS project, and I'm discovering a strange syntax. I've marked the lines with comments below.

file(example) : MyModule.vue

```
const storeCompte = namespace("compte") // namespace is based on 'node_modules\vuex-class\lib\bindings.d.ts'
const storeEvenements = namespace("evenements")

@Component({  // <== ok the @ here is for the decorator 
  components: {
....
.... // some code

export default class PageAgenda extends BasePage {
  @storeCompte.Getter loggedIn!: boolean// <== but what is this @ doing here ?

  @storeRegions.Getter nomRegion!: string  // <== and here ?
  @storeRegions.Getter regionInstance?: Region // <== here too ?
  @storeRegions.Getter listeRegions!: Array<Region>// <== what ?

  public filterMobile = false
  public otherFiltres: EventParams

  mounted(): void {
    // some code
  }

//... the code continues
//...
```

what is the significance of this '@' in this context?

Comment: You already called it decorator. That's correct. `@` decorates a class or its members

Comment: and `@storeCompte.Getter loggedIn!: boolean` is this a decorator too ?

Comment: Yes. The syntax is the same, the role is the same https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: thanks. this is a decorator used in a diffrent manner in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [TypeScript](https://typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) (and [ECMAScript](https://tc39.es/ecma262) as well), the `@` sigil signifies a *decorator*. In TypeScript, it is part of the language, in ECMAScript, it is still [a Stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators).

A *decorator*, as the name implies, *decorates* the language element it is applied to. The language elements that can be decorated are [classes](https://typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#class-decorators), [methods](https://typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#method-decorators), [accessors](https://typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#accessor-decorators), [properties](https://typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#property-decorators), and [parameters](https://typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators).

Note: parameter decorators are a TypeScript-only feature, they are not present in the ECMAScript proposal. Vice-versa, the ECMAScript proposal adds a new class syntax element called *class auto accessors* and decorators for it, whereas class auto accessors do not exist in TypeScript.

*Decorators* are, essentially, functions that take a description of the syntax element to be decorated as an argument and can choose to return a modified version of that syntax element.

In this case, based on the naming, it sounds like the decorator is turning the field it is applied to into a getter.